# lualatex no longer works.. because the memory dump file could not be found

Tags: errors, luatex

```
 restricted system commands enabled.

Sorry, but "C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-luatex.exe" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-luatex.log
```

And then in that file:

```
2020-04-03 05:14:32,286-0600 INFO  miktex-luatex - starting with command line: "C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-luatex.exe" -synctex=1 --fmt=lualatex doubleSidedCards.tex
2020-04-03 05:14:32,354-0600 INFO  miktex-luatex - going to create file: lualatex.fmt
2020-04-03 05:14:32,643-0600 ERROR miktex-luatex - C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2020-04-03 05:14:32,643-0600 ERROR miktex-luatex - output:
2020-04-03 05:14:32,643-0600 ERROR miktex-luatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:

  Unknown format name/engine: lualatex/luatex

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2020-04-03 05:14:32,644-0600 FATAL miktex-luatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2020-04-03 05:14:32,644-0600 FATAL miktex-luatex - Info: fileName="lualatex.fmt"
2020-04-03 05:14:32,644-0600 FATAL miktex-luatex - Source: Programs\TeXAndFriends\luatex\miktex\miktex.cpp
2020-04-03 05:14:32,644-0600 FATAL miktex-luatex - Line: 74
2020-04-03 05:14:32,644-0600 INFO  miktex-luatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

I did try reinstalling `miktex` which actually worked for about two compilations. Then I updated `miktex` and we're right back to not being able to run `lualatex`. I am on Windows 7 running 64-bit miktex. It seemed to work okay if using an engine other than lualatex. Unfortunately that's what I'm using.

Oh yeah I did the classic update, rebuild names database, rebuild formats in miktex console but obviously that does nothing.

Comment: Just for fun and because this is often a problem on miktex. Did you update miktex in both miktex user mode and miktex admin mode? The user mode stuff might not get touched by a reinstall.

Comment: Your formats.ini probably still points to luatex instead of luahbtex. Check what is said about lualatex in settings->formats

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem days ago. On the MikTeX website they explain that they are introducing a [new](https://miktex.org/news) Lua compiler (LuaHB). In the case of LuaLaTeX this is found in: "miktex-portable / texmfs / install / miktex / bin / x64 / miktex-luahbtex.exe"

I updated the instructions to compile in TeXworks and lualatex.fmt is found (portable installation) in: "... \ miktex-portable \ texmfs \ data \ miktex \ data \ le \ luahbtex \ lualatex.fmt"